# Infinite loop while using Matcher in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning regex and I have this fragment of code:

```
private static final String FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN = "^(,Share %)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = ",Share %,\"Date Purchased\",Display Name,Address,Phone,Fax,Mobile,Email,";

    Matcher beginningFileMatcher = Pattern.compile(FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN).matcher(str);
    if (beginningFileMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Regex match!");
    }

    // find() method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if
    // a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
    // not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous
    // match.
    //

    int count = 0;
    while (beginningFileMatcher.find()) { // find not match, we need beginningFileMatcher.reset() but its not 
        // thread-safe.
        count++;
        System.out.println("COUNT ++++++++++++++ :" + count);
    }
}
```

try another way:

```
private static final String FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN = "^(,Share %)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = ",Share %,\"Date Purchased\",Display Name,Address,Phone,Fax,Mobile,Email,";
    Pattern beginningFilePattern = Pattern.compile(FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = beginningFilePattern.matcher(s);

    if (beginningFilePattern.matcher(s).find()) {
        System.out.println("Thread-safe regex match!.");
    }

    int countCount = 0;
    while (beginningFilePattern.matcher(s).find()) { //this cause infinite loop while matcher.find() done as 
        // expected result! Why?
        countCount++;
        System.out.println("COUNT ++++++++++++++ :" + countCount);
    }
}
```

I already comment on that problem in this snippet as above. Is there anyone who can explain why? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you need to check it once use `if`, why `while`? `if (beginningFilePattern.matcher(s).find())`

Comment: unrelated: `countCount` should be initialized to `1`if the first `if`block is true.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: this is code for testing. I need to count how many occurrences exist for some check condition in another place.

Comment: @jhamon: I don't know why? I'm really confused.

Comment: At any rate, there will only be one match, since `^(,Share %)` requires a match at the start of the string.

Comment: on the first solution, the first match is found by the `find` in the `if`block, so `countCount` value should be 1, then the `while` would count the other matches (if any). The best way would be to remove the if block and use only the while.

Comment: @jhamon: No, `count` won't be `1` because `while (beginningFileMatcher.find())` won't execute. Since `find()` will simply return false second time.

Comment: @anubhava that's the problem, it should be 1 when the `if`is true as there was a previous match

Comment: I don't understand your obsession with thread safety. Your code does not involve multithreading, so why worry about thread safety?

Comment: @ThomasKläger: Sorry for my stupidity, actually there is a thing that I'm really confused about. Is Java program running with concurrency mode in modern computer names like a computer with multi-cores in it,  or Java program only running with concurrency mode if I already using `Thread` or `Runnable` in my code?

Comment: A simple java application like your example is always single-threaded. Only when you start using threads (either through the `Thread` class, through `ExecutorService` and related classes or by using Swing) will you have to worry about thread safety. But even then an object that you create and use within a single method is only used from a single thread. (Another thread could execute that same method at the same time, but that other thread would create and use it's own object.)

Comment: @ThomasKläger: Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that you're creating a new `Matcher` instance every time in `if` condition and `while` loop blocks here:

```
if (beginningFilePattern.matcher(s).find()) {
```

and here:

```
while (beginningFilePattern.matcher(s).find())
```

By creating a new instance of `Matcher` you're losing previous state of that and starting match operation every time.

Also note removal of `if` condition before `while` loop to get the `count` right.

You may use this code to fix this:

```
String str = ",Share %,\"Date Purchased\",Display Name,Address,Phone,Fax,Mobile,Email,";

Matcher beginningFileMatcher = Pattern.compile(FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN).matcher(str);

// find() method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if
// a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
// not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous
// match.
//

int count = 0;
while (beginningFileMatcher.find()) { // find not match, we need beginningFileMatcher.reset() but its not 
    if (count == 0)
        System.out.println("Regex match!");
    // thread-safe.
    count++;
    System.out.println("COUNT ++++++++++++++ :" + count);
}

//try another way.
String s = ",Share %,\"Date Purchased\",Display Name,Address,Phone,Fax,Mobile,Email,";
Pattern beginningFilePattern = Pattern.compile(FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = beginningFilePattern.matcher(s);

int countCount = 0;
while (matcher.find()) { // make sure to use matcher object
    if (countCount == 0)
        System.out.println("Thread-safe regex match!");
    countCount++;
    System.out.println("COUNT ++++++++++++++ :" + countCount);
}
```

Comment: It not clear in the question but OP posted 2 version of his code. First one with a single matcher and second one with the infinite loop. Your solution is the same as OP's first one. Still it won't give him the correct result if the matcher matches only once

Comment: It does fix infinite loop problem that OP posted due to stated reason in ansewr.

Comment: @anubhava: Thank you, but is there another way to do this but still ensure thread-safe?

Comment: the do-while is a good idea but it will returns `1` if the pattern doesn't match

Comment: @anubhava: when I do: `beginningFileMatcher.reset()` and then using matcher in while loop.

Comment: @logbasex: Please check updated answer. There is no need to use `.reset()` anywhere.

Comment: @anubhava: This worked fine, sir. But I'm still looking for a simplifier way. Suppose I have one CSV file with 1000 lines. I have to extract the name before the first comma in each line if that name matches my regex (E.g: `^(\w)\s(\w)(?=,)`). What I want to do is replace all matched regex with empty `String` and also count how many lines matched in only one code block.  Are you have any good ideas?

Comment: That can be done easily using regex: `(?m)^\\w+\\s+\\w+(?=,)` in this call: `data = data.replaceAll("(?m)^\\w+\\s+\\w+(?=,)", "");` where `data` is the String object containing complete CSV data.

Comment: With an anchor, it's worked fine, but If I wanna count how many lines matched, I have to do it in another loop. Any suggestion, sir? @anubhava

Comment: Yes to get a count you need a loop of `while (matcher.find())` and you can get count do replacement both in same loop. So instead of `data.replaceAll` you can do `matcher.replaceFirst(""); count++`

Answer (score 1):

Each version of you code has a different issue.

For the version 2 (inifinite loop): You create the matcher in the loop. That means on each iteration, there will be a new matcher, starting at the begining of your String. So the call to `find` will always return the same result, if any.

Your first solution is what you need to do, create a matcher once and then use it by calling `find` in a loop.

The issue is that you call `find`in 2 different places. First in the `if` block, to see if there is any matches in your String, then in the loop.

What if the String contains only 1 matching result?

- The result is returned in the `if`block
- `countCount` is set to `0`
- The while loop try to find the next match but there is none
- the code prints `COUNT : 0`

If you don't reset the matcher before looping, you need to count the result from the `if`block into your counter. Here is a solution with minimal changes:

```
final static String FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN = "^(,Share %)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = ",Share %,\"Date Purchased\",Display Name,Address,Phone,Fax,Mobile,Email,";

    Matcher beginningFileMatcher = Pattern.compile(FILE_BEGINNING_PATTERN).matcher(str);

    int count = 0;
    if (beginningFileMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Regex match!");
        count++; // already a match, increment the counter
    }

    while (beginningFileMatcher.find()) { 
        count++;
        System.out.println("COUNT ++++++++++++++ :" + count);
    }
}
```

Another way would be to remove the if block and use only the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Matcher reset()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#reset())

> Resets this matcher.
>   Resetting a matcher discards all of its explicit state information and sets its append position to zero. The matcher's region is set to the default region, which is its entire character sequence. The anchoring and transparency of this matcher's region boundaries are unaffected.

If you want it thread safe put it inside `synchronize` block

Comment: I'm don't know about `synchronize` block. I need to complete my task in today afternoon.  Is there another way archive thread-safe?

Comment: see an example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, when you call `beginningFilePattern.matcher(s).find()`, you are creating a new instance of the matcher inside the `while` condition. Each of those new matchers will check again from the beginning instead of trying to find the next occurrence. You should try to make your `reset()` call threat safe but keep the same matcher instance.